# Java - Casting Int to Byte - odd results

Tags: java, arrays, bitwise-operators, bytebuffer

I'm performing bitwise operations on blocks 4-bytes large. I've cast the 4-byte blocks into 4-byte integers to do this, using ByteBuffer.

Once they are done, I need to cast them back in to bytes. Using ByteBuffer, I'm performing this. Here's some sample code, with data, to highlight my confusion:

```
int a = 1610612739; //simulate casting the 4-byte  block 60 00 00 03
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.putInt(a);
byte[] b1 = (b.array());
```

Now, after this code I expect `b1` to hold the following:

```
b1[0]: 60
b1[1]: 00
b1[2]: 00
b1[3]: 03
```

But that's not what's happening. Instead, I get

```
b2[0]: 96
b2[1]: 0
b2[2]: 0
b2[3]: 3
```

My sample integer, in binary, should be::

`0110 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011` where the far left bit is the sign.

and `96 00 00 03` in decimal is `2,516,582,403` which is outside Java's 32-bit int range.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: That's because `96 == 0x60`. (Hint: delete the question while not too many people saw it :-)

Comment: +1 for thinking too complicated. ^_^

Comment: After some years of programming you get a list of these. From forgetting to copy a dll and wondering why nothing changes onwards to reading over some code multiple times and missing an error a college sees immediately to ending an if-statement routinely with a semicolon. It happens.

Comment: @Dirgon - don't worry about it. Most of us have facepalm moments. I do too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, you think it is supposed to show in **Hexadecimal** but it  shows in **decimals**. That's it.